# How can I display my Patreon patron's name on my WordPress website using Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have a website made with WordPress and Elementor. I have a patreon page and i have 1 patron.

I want to show my patron name and surname on my wordpress website. Also when new patrons start to support me it must be automaticaly update my website.

I already try to use chatgpt and I did not to figure out unfortunately.

I can make register clients and getting campaign id , client id and token.